# How To Get Parent Details In Couch Db?

Tags: couchdb

Please Help Me

I have Created A databse named  Product

And I have created  2 product documents with id 'P101','P102'

{
   "_id": "P101",
   "_rev": "5-8d1c4b5b7f6e65a5997d4ec5b4346e5f",
   "type": "product",
   "name": "Shirt",
   "hersteller": "oska",
   "price": 11.15
}

{
   "_id": "P102",
   "_rev": "3-8ad956f0c524b1a2396ebdda1ed0afbe",
   "type": "product",
   "name": "Pullover",
   "hersteller": "acme",
   "price": 7.58
}

Now added one Order document with 'P101' as its parent

{
   "_id": "ORD-101",
   "_rev": "7-dbd8cca3b6dc9f4cb3b8bb7e4aec6630",
   "type": "order",
   "orderDate": "01.01.2012",
   "parentProdct": "P101"
}

Now I have added the Report document with 'ORD-101' as its parent

{
   "_id": "REPORT-101",
   "_rev": "10-c57e3c039a44d95d6bd40d8a83a951da",
   "type": "REPORT",
   "parentOrder": "ORD-102"
}

After this all I have added the design document with corresponding view functions

{
   "_id": "_design/proddesign",
   "_rev": "87-d1b0a8c8cdfe569bbf9805df4918af4f",
   "rev": "3-productrev",
   "views": {
       "fifth": {
           "map": "function(doc){if(doc.type=='REPORT'){emit(doc._id,{_id:doc.reportDet});}}"
       } 
   }
}

..
This give me only the Parent off Report document.Actually I want to print the details of corresponding parent of order document also.

ie details 'P101' also..

How Can I achive that ..Pls Help

Comment: Shouldn't `"parentOrder": "ORD-102"` be `"parentOrder": "ORD-101"`?

Comment: I might just be ignorant but I seriously struggle with the use case for parent and child orders in couch. Have you considered Neo4J?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following data (note: _rev and unused docs removed from your example):

```
{ 
  "_id": "P101", 
  "type": "product", 
  "name": "Shirt", 
  "hersteller": "oska", 
  "price": 11.15 
}

{ 
  "_id": "ORD-101", 
  "type": "order", 
  "orderDate": "01.01.2012", 
  "product": "P101" 
}

{ 
  "_id": "REPORT-101", 
  "type": "report", 
  "order": "ORD-101",
  "product": "P101" 
}
```

You'll want to do something along the lines of:

```
if (doc.type == "product")
    emit([doc._id], doc.type)
if (doc.type == "order")
    emit([doc.product, doc._id], doc.type)
if (doc.type == "report")
    emit([doc.product, doc.order, doc._id], doc.type)
```

Which will result in view output like:

```
[
    [["P101"], "product"], 
    [["P101", "ORD-101"], "order"], 
    [["P101", "ORD-101", "REPORT-101"], "report"]
]
```

Which if you query with

```
?startkey=["P101"]&endkey=["P101",{}]
```

Will give you the product P101 as well as all of the orders and reports for that product.